# How to get month index from month name using date-fns library

Tags: javascript, date-fns

I need to get the month index number from the month name using the `date-fns` library. Earlier I was using `moment.js`, it was straightforward with `moment.js`

```
  moment().month('March').format('M'); 
// Month name will be variable and I don't want to use static dictionary to get index number
```

How to achieve the same using the `date-fns` library? I thought to use `format(date, 'M');` but it needs complete date and only month name is available.

Please suggest. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think so date-fns has any thing like that available at the moment https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/blob/master/src/getMonth/index.ts

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you need

If you are using date-fns library

```
function getMonthCount(month){
    const result = getMonth(new Date(`${month} 1`))+1;
}
```

If you don't want to use any library

```
function getMonthCount(month){
    const sometime= new Date(`${month} 1`);
    console.log(sometime.getMonth()+1);
}
```

NOTE: this will return month in range [1,12]

Comment: new Date(`${month} 1`) what is 1 here?

Comment: what i am doing here is that i am converting the month into a date .                                            new Date(${month} 1) this will return a date which will be first day of the month                       . so 1 over here tell that you need first day of the month

Comment: got it, thanks! this worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

date-fns comes with handy functions out of the box

```js
import {getMonth} from 'date-fns'

const date = new Date()

const month = getMonth(date) + 1
```

getMonth returns a number, you add +1 because it starts with 0.
The result you'll get is the number of the month.
If let's say the month is March, you'll get 3